# Replace each cell in a dataframe by the value of a dict inside each cell pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is my dataframe :

```
df2

0   1   2   3   4   5   

0   {'tag_name': 'fre'}     {'tag_name': 'bgs'}     {'tag_name': 'fa'}  {'tag_name': 'cu'}  {'tag_name': 'bi'}
1   {'tag_name': 'fr2e'}    {'tag_name': 'b1gs'}    {'tag_name': 'f3'}  {'tag_name': 'czu'}     {'tag_name': 'bRi'}
```

So i would like for each cell to have the value of ['tag_name'] inside and not the dict.

thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda axis: [axis[0]] + [x['tag_name'] for x in axis[1:]], axis=1)
```

Or like suggested with type check:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda axis: [x['tag_name'] if type(x) == dict else x for x in axis], axis=1)
```

Comment: TypeError: ("'NoneType' object is not subscriptable", 'occurred at index 0')  :/

Comment: Seems like there are missing values in your real data. So, you could use an if-else block to check whether they are of type `dict` and alternatively I'd recommend the `get` method in case any of the keys are found to be missing.

Comment: Nickly Maveli, I added a clause to validate the type.